# Xcode 5.0.1 + Mavericks signing identities are always Revoked

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, certificate

I've been using the new OSX + Xcode for a while and I'm having troubles with certificates. All my "Signing Identities" have status "Revoked".

I tried revoking all old certificates and creating new ones. Even after freshly creating a new certificate request, submitting it on the web (developer.apple.com), downloading the new certificate and adding it to the keychain, when I turn Xcode on and refresh identities they are still Revoked.
I tried doing so in Xcode automatically, which revoked my old certificates and requested new ones, after it is done the new Signing identity is Revoked as well. 
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I have been doing this a lot of times before and I didn't have any problems... 
I also use multiple developer accounts and this happens on all of them, so I guess it's either Xcode or Keychain (OSX) problem. 
Any suggestions?

(Certificates on the image were created a minute ago, distribution certificate was created automatically by Xcode and I development certificate myself, everything is OK in keychain)

[image: Signing identity status always Revoked]

Comment: If you login to the developer portal, what is the status of the certificates?

Comment: Everything is ok online (developer portal) only xcode thinks they are revoked (even those, which he created a sec ago)... When I try to run the app on device with those certficates and appropriate provisioning profiles, it works, but when I try to submit an app to the app store I'm getting some errors (I'll probably update the question and mention it there later, I'm on my ipad now)

Comment: Open keychain access. Do you have the certificates there?

Comment: Yes, I have public and private keys there + correctly assigned certificates

Comment: Can you upgrade Xcode to 5.0.2? This is a realy weird problem... but I got also some trouble with mavericks and my prov. profiles.

Comment: Hi @Zero3nna, I already updated the xCode to 5.0.2, but I didn't need to submit any app yet (I'm doing it on friends mac, where everything works fine). But when I checked certificates, they are still revoked... I'll be getting my new mac soon so I'll try to get it to work there again.

Comment: Did you fix this? I am also facing same problem

Comment: @Subha I don't think so, I ended up reinstalling the xcode, I didn't have any problems like this in recent releases

Comment: @haluzak, Thanks. I fixed this by deleting all certificates from Keychain, deleting apple account from Xcode and freshly downloaded everything again. Xcode started showing valid status :)